# Samba server 3.6.3 crashes on simple setup on Linux Mint 13

Tags: linux-mint, samba

I try to get smbd running on Linux Mint 13 on kernel 3.6.3-030603-generic. This is what I do:

`sudo apt-get install samba`, then install this minimal /etc/samba/smb.conf:

```
[global] 
    workgroup = wkb
    security = user
    browsable = yes 
    local master = yes 
[temp] 
    path = /tmp 
    public = yes
```

Then I type:
`smbclient -L localhost -U%` and get the following error:

```
Domain=[WKB] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.3]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_PIPE_BROKEN
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I debug it further? I can't find the reference to this error message on the Net.

Update:

I put `sudo smbpasswd -U Adam` and filled in some password.

Then, when I connect to the share from Windows, after filling in username "Adam" and the same password, first I do see the correct share list:

[image: share list]

But then, when I try to enter the share "tmp" (to which the user "Adam", spelled with capital "A") has all read/modify rights, I've got the following error message:

[image: error message]

It is interesting, that when I subsequently try to refresh the share list this message persists, as if samba had crashed. But the `service status smbd` insists, that `smbd start/running, process 27309`...

But it must be a crash of some sort, since at the end of `/var/log/samba/log.smbd` I can find:

```
[2012/11/13 10:01:35.281800,  0] lib/fault.c:372(dump_core)
  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
[2012/11/13 10:01:35.296359,  0] lib/util.c:1117(smb_panic)
  PANIC (pid 29359): sys_setgroups failed
[2012/11/13 10:01:35.303973,  0] lib/util.c:1221(log_stack_trace)
  BACKTRACE: 21 stack frames:
   #0 smbd(log_stack_trace+0x1a) [0x7ff64ea37aea]
   #1 smbd(smb_panic+0x25) [0x7ff64ea37bc5]
   #2 smbd(+0x163be6) [0x7ff64e782be6]
   #3 smbd(set_sec_ctx+0x8f) [0x7ff64e782f0f]
   #4 smbd(+0x152db5) [0x7ff64e771db5]
   #5 smbd(+0x17ae2b) [0x7ff64e799e2b]
   #6 smbd(+0x17b76e) [0x7ff64e79a76e]
   #7 smbd(make_connection+0x1ea) [0x7ff64e79aaea]
   #8 smbd(reply_tcon_and_X+0x1dc) [0x7ff64e74b82c]
   #9 smbd(+0x176fa4) [0x7ff64e795fa4]
   #10 smbd(+0x1773bb) [0x7ff64e7963bb]
   #11 smbd(+0x1777d3) [0x7ff64e7967d3]
   #12 smbd(run_events_poll+0x34e) [0x7ff64ea478ae]
   #13 smbd(smbd_process+0x812) [0x7ff64e797f42]
   #14 smbd(+0x68666f) [0x7ff64eca566f]
   #15 smbd(run_events_poll+0x34e) [0x7ff64ea478ae]
   #16 smbd(+0x428a4a) [0x7ff64ea47a4a]
   #17 smbd(_tevent_loop_once+0x90) [0x7ff64ea485d0]
   #18 smbd(main+0xed0) [0x7ff64e716030]
   #19 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed) [0x7ff64b5c176d]
   #20 smbd(+0xf7515) [0x7ff64e716515]
[2012/11/13 10:01:35.305623,  0] lib/fault.c:372(dump_core)
  dumping core in /var/log/samba/cores/smbd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved upgrading to samba 3.6.7

https://www.monlore.nl/blog/?p=226

Answer (score 0):

Check if daemon started:

```
sudo service smbd status
```

Then check log files in /var/log/samba

Comment: Thank you. No. It is running, otherwise it would respond with `Connection to localhost failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)` and not with `NT_STATUS_PIPE_BROKEN`. The `sudo service smbd status` gives `smbd start/running, process 29290`

Comment: I've added the crash log. It seems the samba crashes...

Comment: This problem seems to be related to the groups the user is member of. How many of them are?

Comment: None. The user Adam is not a member of any group. Should he be one?...

Comment: to be sure run the command 'groups Adam'

Comment: `$ groups Adam` gives 
`Adam : Adam`... Ok. But regardless of group membership "Adam" has the access to the /tmp folder. I checked it by `sudo su Adam`, `cd /tmp` and `ls`...

Comment: There is a known issue with samba when user is member of too many groups, but it seems it is not your case.

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem with 3.6.3 , I am not happy with ubuntu server , it lost me a day to find what is the problem.
I upgraded to 3.6.7 and it fix everything !!!
Ubuntu server is going to worse every new version !

Comment: It was enough to state that updating fixed your problems, and it would have been nice to detail which ones.